# How to execute my first file in XML, DTD and and XHTML?

Tags: xml, dtd

I am new with xml, I am trying to make work my first example but I am not sure about the result that  I have.  I am sending the file to a browser 
This is DTD file:

```
<!ELEMENT liste_acteurs (acteur*)>
<!ELEMENT acteur (prenom,nom,naissance,nationalite,photo?,site?,biographie)>
<!ATTLIST acteur id  ID #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT nom (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT prenom (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT naissance (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nationalite (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT photo EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST photo source CDATA #REQUIRED
                alt    CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT site EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST site url CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT biographie (p*)>
<!ELEMENT p (#PCDATA | refacteur | film | realisateur | annee)*>
<!ELEMENT refacteur (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST refacteur code IDREF #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT film (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT realisateur (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT annee (#PCDATA)>
```

This is XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE measurements PUBLIC "-//American Sentinel//XML Applications//EN" "acteurs.dtd">

<liste_acteurs >
    <!-- Clint Eastwood -->
    <acteur id="clint">
        <prenom>Clint</prenom>
        <nom>Eastwood</nom>
        <naissance>31 Mai 1930</naissance>
        <nationalite>américaine</nationalite>
        <photo source="clint.jpg" alt="Clint Eastwood" />
        <site url="http://www.clinteastwood.net/" />
        <biographie>
            <p>
Né d'un père comptable, le jeune Clinton mène avec ses parents une vie de nomade. Il passe son adolescence à Oakland et ne pense pas du tout à devenir acteur. Il fait des petits boulots sans grande conviction. Puis il part à l'armée où il fait des rencontres décisives et obtient du travail chez Universal. Il fait sa première apparition en 
                <annee>1955</annee> dans 
                <film>La Revanche de la créature</film> puis enchaîne les petits rôles dans cinq films où personne ne le remarque véritablement.

            </p>
            <p>
Avec le drame 
                <film>Million dollar baby</film>, le cinéaste obtient une véritable consécration en remportant, douze ans après 
                <film>Impitoyable</film>, l'Oscar du Meilleur film et du Meilleur réalisateur, ses comédiens 
                <refacteur code="hilary">Hilary Swank</refacteur> et 
                <refacteur code="morgan">Morgan Freeman</refacteur> repartant avec les statuettes de La Meilleure actrice et du Meilleur second rôle masculin.

            </p>
        </biographie>
    </acteur>
    <!-- Hilary Swank -->
    <acteur id="hilary">
        <!-- Hilary Swank : le prénom -->
        <prenom>Hilary</prenom>
        <!-- Hilary Swank : le nom -->
        <nom>Swank</nom>
        <naissance>30 Juillet 1974</naissance>
        <nationalite>américaine</nationalite>
        <photo source="hilaryswank.jpg" alt="Hilary Swank" />
        <site url="http://www.hilaryswankfan.com/" />
        <biographie>
            <p>
Championne de natation, Hilary Swank s'oriente rapidement vers le métier d'actrice. A l'âge de dix-huit ans, elle fait une courte apparition dans 
                <film>Buffy, tueuse de vampires</film> en 
                <annee>1992</annee>, une comédie fantastique de Fran Rubel Kuzui, et décroche en 
                <annee>1994</annee> le rôle-titre de 
                <film>Miss Karaté Kid</film> de Christopher Cain.

            </p>
            <p>
C'est 
                <film>Boys don't cry</film>, un drame de 
                <realisateur>Kimberly Peirce</realisateur>, qui la révèle véritablement au grand public en 
                <annee>2000</annee>. Sa prestation du travesti Brandon Teena lui vaut l'Oscar et le Golden Globe de la Meilleure actrice, les prix d'interprétation des New York Film Critics, Los Angeles Film Critics et Chicago Film Critics, ainsi que le Broadcast Film Critics.

            </p>
            <p>
En 
                <annee>2005</annee>, elle rafle pour la deuxième fois (et en seulement deux nominations) l'Oscar de la Meilleure actrice grâce à sa performance de boxeuse surentraînée par 
                <refacteur code="clint">Clint Eastwood</refacteur> dans 
                <film>Million dollar baby</film>.

            </p>
        </biographie>
    </acteur>
    <!-- Morgan Freeman -->
    <acteur id="morgan">
        <prenom>Morgan</prenom>
        <nom>Freeman</nom>
        <naissance>1 Juin 1937</naissance>
        <nationalite>américaine</nationalite>
        <photo source="freeman.jpg" alt="Morgan Freeman" />
        <biographie>
            <p>
Morgan Freeman est diplômé du lycée de Greenwood, dans le Mississippi. A dix-huit ans, il s'engage dans l'Air Force et, une fois ses obligations militaires accomplies, s'installe en Californie pour étudier la danse et l'art dramatique au Los Angeles City College. C'est à Broadway qu'il fait ses débuts de comédien en 
                <annee>1967</annee>.

            </p>
            <p>
A 68 ans, il obtient enfin la reconnaissance de la profession en remportant l'Oscar du Meilleur second rôle masculin pour sa prestation d'ancien boxeur borgne dans 
                <film>Million dollar baby</film> (
                <annee>2005</annee>) de son fidèle ami 
                <refacteur code="clint">Clint Eastwood</refacteur>.

            </p>
        </biographie>
    </acteur>
</liste_acteurs>
```

The result is:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<liste_acteurs>
<!--  Clint Eastwood  -->
<acteur id="clint">
<prenom>Clint</prenom>
<nom>Eastwood</nom>
<naissance>31 Mai 1930</naissance>
<nationalite>américaine</nationalite>
<photo source="clint.jpg" alt="Clint Eastwood"/>
<site url="http://www.clinteastwood.net/"/>
<biographie>
<p>
Né d'un père comptable, le jeune Clinton mène avec ses parents une vie de nomade. Il passe son adolescence à Oakland et ne pense pas du tout à devenir acteur. Il fait des petits boulots sans grande conviction. Puis il part à l'armée où il fait des rencontres décisives et obtient du travail chez Universal. Il fait sa première apparition en
<annee>1955</annee>
dans
<film>La Revanche de la créature</film>
puis enchaîne les petits rôles dans cinq films où personne ne le remarque véritablement.
</p>
<p>
Avec le drame
<film>Million dollar baby</film>
, le cinéaste obtient une véritable consécration en remportant, douze ans après
<film>Impitoyable</film>
, l'Oscar du Meilleur film et du Meilleur réalisateur, ses comédiens
<refacteur code="hilary">Hilary Swank</refacteur>
et
...........................
```

Firstly, I am not sure about the result. I don't understand this sentence:

```
  This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing or what you are expecting. Are you sending the file to a browser (that's what seems to be happening)? In that case you have not provided an XSLT stylesheet to translate XML to HTML.  Please explain more clearly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JimGarrison, yes sir that is it i am sending the file to a browser, I expect to find an interface,

Comment: You seem to be missing a basic understanding of the process. You are sending XML to the browser (the DTD is not important here). The browser needs an XSLT stylesheet to convert the XML to HTML tags and layout the presentation.  Explaining how to do this is far beyond the scope of StackOverflow Question and Answer format.